# How to List out product collection in simple table using knowckout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have code like below i have tried to implement it with magento custom module.but didn't get it working as it should can any one please guide me how can i implement this.Here i just want to list down product name,price,sku in the below html table.How can i achieve this by pure knockout js.

PHTML file

```
    <?php $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "Kite_Boxes/js/productrender",
                    "exampleMessage": "<?= __('Hello This is content from ko!') ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
  <h2 data-bind="text: message"></h2>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columnNames">
            <th> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columnNames">
            <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Component js code.

```
     define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return function(config) {
        this.message = ko.observable(config.exampleMessage);
         var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
        self.columnNames = ko.computed(function () {
            if (self.items().length === 0)
                return [];
            var props = [];
            var obj = self.items()[0];
            for (var name in obj)
                props.push(name);
            //return props;


        });
        var vm = new VM();

          ko.applyBindings(vm);

          vm.items.push({
              'Name': 'John',
              'Age': 25,
              'test':125
          });
          vm.items.push({
              'Name': 'Morgan',
              'Age': 26
          });
    }
});
```

I have imlimented like this but it gives error like this.
[Erorr Screenshot from Browser console](https://www.screencast.com/t/EmmPQVwF)

Comment: Because of your edit your question has been pushed into the reopen review queue. Could you explain why it is no longer a duplicate of the referred question?

Comment: because above question is different then duplicated.I have asked to use binding and applying on ko js.I have also describe how i did implemented and stated error.